# How to maintain and apply aspect ratio of images in extjs4

Tags: image, extjs4, aspect-ratio

I am working in extjs4. I am trying to display image by using following component=

```
xtype : 'image',
height : 600,
width : 800,
src :me.imageSrc
```

Where,me.imageSrc is having image path. But sometimes image is shown as blurred or expanded if image's height and width is too large. So how to calculate aspect ratio and apply it in extjs4 in order to show images properly.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the size of the loaded image you need to listen the "load" event on the image element, in the listener callback you have access to the with and height.

Here's the code that makes the magic:

```
var img = imageCmp.imgEl
img.on('load',function(){
     Ext.Msg.alert('IMG Size',img.getWidth()+'x'+img.getHeight());
});
```

Here's a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/crysfel/utUA2/

Make sure you remove the hardcoded width and height ;)

Comment: Thanx for reply sir. I can get image's original height and width as you suggested way. But i wanted to know how to apply these new height and width with proper maintainance of aspect ratio..

Comment: You can use the setWidth and setHeight methods from the image component. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Img-method-setHeight